# Printing Entire QWebView Content does not result as expected

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

I have been trying to get the QWebView printed. Initially it looked simple.

```
class myView:public QWebView
{
...
}
```

In one of the public Member Function of myView

```
  QPrinter printer;


  printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
  printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);

  QPrintDialog *dlog = new QPrintDialog (&printer, this);

  qDebug () <<" HoHoooo.. Going to print ";
  if ( dlog->exec ()  != QDialog::Accepted)
  {
      qDebug () <<"Printing Not accepted.. :( ";

  }
  else
  {
      print(&printer);

  }
```

The output for the print is not getting properly. Kindly suggest, if i miss something?

Comment: 'not getting properly'? any details on whats being printed wrongly?

Comment: @evilruff, alignment issues, button are not in proper place like that

Comment: but rendering on a screen looks ok?

Comment: Yup, it looks perfectly OK. :(.

Comment: I had to use a resolution of 100 (instead of 300) to get the page to display properly.

Answer (score 1):

Check the HTML code you want to print if it conforms to the HTML specification (use a HTML-checking tool!), even though your code renders fine to the screen, print-rendering is totally different code and thus can behave differently in case your HTML page does not conform to the standard.

In case it conforms, you can check printing in Safari or any other WebKit based browser to see, if it prints correctly there.